# Is there a way to convert a string with multiple decimal points to a double in Scala?

Tags: scala, type-conversion

Let's say I have strings like `"9....3"` and `"0........3"` and `".......2"` is it possible to convert these into Doubles such as `9.3` and `0.3` and `0.2` in Scala? Obviously using `toDouble` wouldn't work.

Answer (score 3):

First, let's replace all consecutive dots to just one. Then attempt to parse the String.

```
"9....3".replaceAll("\\.{2,}", ".").toDoubleOption.getOrElse(default = 0.0d)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is regex pattern match approach

```
def multipleDotsToDouble(s: String): Option[Double] = {
  val Pattern = """(\d*)(\.*)(\d*)""".r
  s match {
    case Pattern(h,_,t) => s"$h.$t".toDoubleOption
    case _ => None
  }
}

multipleDotsToDouble(".......2")
```

which outputs

```
res6: Option[Double] = Some(0.2)
```